# Considerations for updating Android app using Android API to Google API

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I have an Android geolocation application released into the market named *apna ilaka*.

It is using Android API level 2.1. In order to allow a user to add places I would like to display a Google map with which the user could find different locations and would be able to add place indicators and information.

Following are my questions :

1. Do I really need to change my Android API level to Google API level in config path?
2. Since my app is already in market if I upload this new apk on market will it create any issue in updating the software on user side?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update the API level of you app if you want to use any api that are higher than the currently set level.

Supporting multiple API levels can be tricky but it isn't a nightmare, check out this great post by google on this subject:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess you are talking about "Google API" versus "Android API"? If you need Google Maps you will need to use "Google API" as it contains the Maps libraries. Otherwise you could not use Maps classes when developing/compiling.
2. No, as far as I know you should not have any problems.